# how to write below logic in java 8 using stream API?

Tags: java-8

I have below arrayList. I want to add student Object if studentname is same.  Example if studentname is  rahul I want to add 24+25. I can do it without using stream. How to do it with stream API in java 8 ? I want answer in key value pair.

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
arraylist.add(new Student(223, "Chaitanya", 26));
arraylist.add(new Student(245, "Rahul", 24));
arraylist.add(new Student(246, "Rahul", 25));
```

Student class contains these property:

```
    private String studentname;
    private int rollno;
    private int studentmarks;
```

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify what are the problems you've encountered?

Comment: This has been asked in recent interview for me. I am not getting how to solve it in java 8. i tried searching for it. still no luck

Comment: Try it out with loop, at list you would have the logic of the solution. That would be helpful for you to understand how to address the same problem with streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Java 8 stream API ::**

Please find the code below:

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

  private String studentName;
  private int rollNo;
  private int studentMarks;

  public Student(String studentName, int rollNo, int studentMarks) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
    this.studentMarks = studentMarks;
  }

  public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
  }

  public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
  }

  public int getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
  }

  public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
  }

  public int getStudentMarks() {
    return studentMarks;
  }

  public void setStudentMarks(int studentMarks) {
    this.studentMarks = studentMarks;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
        "studentName='" + studentName + '\'' +
        ", rollNo=" + rollNo +
        ", studentMarks=" + studentMarks +
        '}';
  }
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student("Rahul",101,320);
    Student s2 = new Student("Rahul",102,420);
    Student s3 = new Student("Mohit",103,520);
    Student s4 = new Student("Rohit",104,620);
    Student s5 = new Student("Mohit",105,720);

    List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);

    Map<String,Integer> map =
        studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStudentName,
        LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.summingInt(Student::getStudentMarks)));

    System.out.println(map);
  }
```

**Output:**

```
{Rahul=740, Mohit=1240, Rohit=620}
```

Comment: Hi @girdhar , This was really helpful , but can you please explain why you used linkedhashmap ? and after groupby studentname what you did?

Comment: Hi @UmeshSulakude, Thanks for the appreciation, I have used linkedhashmap in order to have the insertion order preserved for the data and moreover you can also use other implementations of Map as well and if you do not want to use then it will take as a Hashmap implementation by default.

Without any Map: 

Map<String,Integer> map =
    studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStudentName,Collectors.summingInt(Student::getStudentMarks)));

If sorting is required you can use TreeMap::new instead of LinkedHashMap::new